# Which one of these 2 is more hardy?

Tags: plant-recommendations

I have a pittosporum here and an euonymus. Not sure which variety though. I've never used either one in the landscape and i have room for only one. Which one is more drought tolerant, heat tolerant and cold hardy?[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

In terms of cold, the *Euonymus japonicus* is hardier; in regard to heat, all I can tell you is that *Pittosporum tenuifolium* grows well in USDA zones 9-11, and the Euonymus in USDA zones 6-9.

The other thing to take into account is the eventual overall size - *Pittosporum tenuifolium* can get up to 30 feet, whereas *Euonymus fortunei* typically reaches between 10 and 13 feet.

Comment: I would say Pittosporum  also grows well in zone 8

Comment: There are variegated E. fortunei cultivars that are both harider (zone 4) and shorter (18 in). They also creep can about the landscape, almost as minor groundcovers - for example, https://plants.oaklandnursery.com/12130001/Plant/6425/Variegated_Wintercreeper/)